# Xamarin iOS misplaced layout after rotation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a very simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MenuLayoutTest" x:Class="MenuLayoutTest.MenuLayoutTestPage">
    <ContentView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
            <ContentView x:Name="AppPageTopBar" HeightRequest="70" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
            <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ContentView x:Name="AppPageModuleContent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
                <ContentView x:Name="AppPageSideMenu" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,244,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="HeightProportional" BackgroundColor="Fuchsia" IsVisible="False"  Padding="12">
                    <ContentView BackgroundColor="Green"/>
                </ContentView>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

with the following code behind that simply toggles the visibility of the fuchsia / green area:

```
public partial class MenuLayoutTestPage : ContentPage
{
    public MenuLayoutTestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ICommand command = new MyCommand(AppPageSideMenu);

        AppPageTopBar.GestureRecognizers.Add(
            new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = command
        });
    }

    public class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly View view;

        public MyCommand(View view)
        {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            view.IsVisible = !view.IsVisible;
        }
    }
}
```

If we open the app in portrait mode and tap the yellow area we will see:

[image: expected layout]

But after a few rotations and show / hide options the layout goes like this.

[image: broken layout]

I have managed to reproduce it 100% both on iOS Simulator and iPad with the following steps:

- kill the app and restart in portrait mode
- rotate left twice
- tap the yellow area to show fuchsia / green area
- tap again to hide it
- rotate left twice
- tap the yellow area to show fuchsia / green area
- tap again to hide it
- rotate right **once**
- tap the yellow area to show fuchsia / green area
- tap again to hide it
- rotate right **once**
- tap the yellow area to show fuchsia / green area
- you should have seen the broken layout

**Edit 1**

Here you can find the sample solution: [MenuLayoutTest](https://www.dropbox.com/s/15dmjr7lqhzgvvz/MenuLayoutTest.zip?dl=0)

**Edit 2**

And I was able to reproduce it on Nexus 9 as well :(

**Edit 3**

A [bug #43186](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43186) has been reported.

Comment: I forgot to put Xamarin version information but I was using 2.3.1.114 and as already written, it was tested on iOS simulator but iPad Air 2 as well.

Comment: you need to follow the steps carefully

Comment: I have just added a link to the solution archive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking. A bug has been reported.